# Error loading Newtonsoft.Json in ASP.net Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get the following error when running my ASP.net Core 1.0 MVC site.  It started after adding references to local projects in the same solution.  The references all state to add a tag to Web.config, but obviously that's not going to work with ASP.Net Core and reading the appsettings.json file is where it's failing.

`An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch.`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had to go through all the projects in the solution and change them to use the .Net Framework 4.6.  Evidently the source of this problem was fixed going from 4.5.x to 4.6.